# Is there a more efficient way of getting an object by related list?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, code

I've started programming in Salesforce in January 2015. Most of my code uses this methodology : :

```
List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();

for(Account account : accounts) {

     accountIds.add(account.id);

}

List<Contact> contacts = [Select id, Account__c from Contact where Account__c in : accountIds];

for(Account account : accounts) {
   for(Contact contact : contacts) {
      if(contact.Account__c = account.id) {
         //Do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Basically I want to use the ids from some accounts to get more objects based on those ids, then I want to manipulate data based on the ids matching.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in a trigger (not before insert), you can get the ids like this:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = Trigger.newMap.keyset();
```

If you are not in a trigger, you can build a set like this (assuming your account list is called accountList):

```
Set<Id> accountIds = (new Map<Id,Account>(accountList)).keySet();
```

You may also want the map implicitly defined above, so you could define it also:

```
Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>(accountList);
```

You can query directly to a map

```
//get the contacts, indexed by contact id.
Map<Id,Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>([Select id, Account__c from Contact where  Account__c in : accountIds]);
```

For the loop, use maps to simplify:

```
//you can either loop through accounts or contacts, as both are maps.
for(Account account : accountMap.values()) {
   Contact cont = contactMap.get(acct.ContactId);
   if (cont == null){
       continue;
   }
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Beautiful this answered my exact question. Thank you!

Comment: No worries bro :)

Answer (score 0):

List will carry duplicates so I prefer to take Set in place of the list

```
    //List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();

    set<Id> accountIds = new set<Id>();

    for(Account account : accounts) {

         accountIds.add(account.id);

    }
    Map<Id, Contact>  cntMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();

    List<Contact> contacts = [Select id, Account__c 
                              from Contact 
                              where Account__c in : accountIds];

    for(Contact  cnt : contacts){
        cntMap.put(cnt.AccountId, Cnt);
    }

    for(Account account : accounts) {
        Contact cont = cntMap.get(account.Id);
      // for(Contact contact : contacts) {
          if(cont.Account__c = account.id) {
             //Do stuff
          }
      // }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Do we have to create the accountIds set every time we want to do something like this?